# agGrid AngularJS 1.x examples are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ag-grid

During evaluation of agGrid by using AngularJS. I've found that on [agGrid Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php)  examples of [AngularJS](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-grid/index.php) are not working. I've found exception on Internet Explorer console:

> Failed to instantiate module agGrid due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'agGrid' is not available!

Can anybody fix that example, so we can explore this control thoroughly?

Comment: make sure your IE is supported version, and post an issue? - https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);
```

before you initialize your module

```
var module = angular.module("example", ["agGrid"]);
```

[Source](https://ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-data-grid/index.php)